# How to configure multiple view resolvers in spring4?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-4

How to configure multiple view resolvers in spring4 in order to prevent a conflict between them? As for example:

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }
```

There are explanations for xml-configuration on the Internet, but I haven't seen any for spring4 java-configuration.

Comment: the same as in XML... Why would it be different. When using an `InternalResourceViewResolver` make sure it always is the last `ViewResolver` (but that is the same with XML based configuration).

Comment: [`ViewResolverRegistry`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewResolverRegistry.html), see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-groovymarkup-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link which you can use:

https://blog.frankel.ch/chaining-url-view-resolvers-in-spring-mvc/#gsc.tab=0